# Why list printed in right order but set not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set

Here is my code:

```
my_list=[2794, 2798, 2817, 2820, 2821, 2823, 2824, 2826, 2829, 2831, 2831, 2831, 2839, 2842, 2843, 2845, 2847, 2850, 2851, 2854, 2855, 2856, 2857, 2858, 2859, 2862, 2864, 2865]

for i in my_list:
    print(i)


print("\n\n")

my_set = set(my_list)

for i in my_set:
    print(i)
```

output:

```
2794
2798
2817
2820
2821
2823
2824
2826
2829
2831
2831
2831
2839
2842
2843
2845
2847
2850
2851
2854
2855
2856
2857
2858
2859
2862
2864
2865



2817
2820
2821
2823
2824
2826
2829
2831
2839
2842
2843
2845
2847
2850
2851
2854
2855
2856
2857
2858
2859
2862
2864
2865
2794
2798
```

**Question:** Why list (in ascending) and set (in some other) are printed in different order?

Comment: Sets are unordered.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Any way to make them ordered?

Comment: set is unordered and un-indexed data structure. where as list is ordered data stucture.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because as @user2357112supportsMonica said, `sets` are unordered. There is an ordered set though which you can see [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/).

Comment: I think it is simpler to use an `OrderedDict` or from Python 3.7 just a regular good ol' `dict`

Answer (score 0):

set is unordered and un-indexed data structure. where as list is ordered data stucture.

convert it to list

```
for i in list(my_set):
    print(i)
```

Comment: converting a `set` to a `list` and iterating on it gives the same order as iterating directly on the `set`.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!